# How to try and simulate a given particle effect?

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

For a university assignment I have to design a particle system in webGL.

I would love to try and simulate the following kind of effect of ink in water:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzkB574jivA

Is simulating a given effect like this simply a case of trial and error?

Any pointers or good quality relevant resources would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for "pointers" is too broad to be answered well, and asking for external resources is considered off-topic. This site is more for helping with specific issues that you've encountered with code you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computational Fluid Dynamics, CFD, is a huge field within computer graphics. It's not trivial at all. It's basically solving the Navier-Stokes equation which describes the basic properties of incompressible fluids.

There are several approaches to simulate fluids. Jos Stam's (euler based) "Stable Fluids" and Fedkiw's level set based Ghost Fluids have been improved over the years, faster, better vorticity, less mass discrepancy, etc. The (lagrangian) particle based approach SPH, Smoothed-Particle Hydrodynamics, is easy to implement but may not be what you're looking for. Dive into the SIGGRAPH proceedings.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!